# How to get videoId when video is uploaded on Vimeo

Tags: c#, ios, node.js, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

How do I get the videoId after a video is uploaded on vimeo? When we call delete upload ticket, we have confirmed that the upload is successful and we are getting a response url like this url=https://api.vimeo.com/users/111243975/uploads/319650191?video_file_id=1786656414&upgrade=true&signature=4c02359068ec5a31cea3b633f6b5f9cf. Here we have video_file_id but not the actual videoId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a deprecated upload method (the "resumable" PUT method), so its documentation is no longer available on the Vimeo Developer Site. Luckily, the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170821150317/https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-upload) has those docs saved.

After you make the final DELETE call to that endpoint, the video uri is returned in the location header of the response.

Answer (score 0):

Pow, Brow, its correct!

**Location: /videos/555380765**

{Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, private
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: /videos/555380765
X-RateLimit-Limit: 500
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 499
X-RateLimit-Reset: 2021-05-26T19:57:59+00:00
Request-Hash: 2461d148
X-BApp-Server: api-v10808-f5ldq
X-Vimeo-DC: ge
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish
Date: Wed, 26 May 2021 19:57:00 GMT
X-Served-By: cache-bwi5155-BWI, cache-cgh11141-CGH
X-Cache: MISS, MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0, 0
X-Timer: S1622059020.784666,VS0,VE594
Vary: Accept, Vimeo-Client-Id
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

}

Comment: I think you can elaborate on this a bit more please and maybe also include a link to the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to hunt around for this one too, so for other stuck on this:

check https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#complete_streaming_upload

essentially you have to make `DELETE` req to:

[https://api.vimeo.com/users/{userId}/uploads/{ticketID-or-uploadID}?signature={signature}&video_file_id={videoFileID}](https://api.vimeo.com/users/%7BuserId%7D/uploads/%7BticketID-or-uploadID%7D?signature=%7Bsignature%7D&video_file_id=%7BvideoFileID%7D)

the video ID is returned as `Location` header ie. `/videos/{video_id}`

`signature` and `videoFileID` are in 'upload_link_secure' or 'upload_link' links that are returned in the response payload when creating upload ticket / upload authentication.

Good luck :)